# Case feed - Email publisher entering free email address

Tags: servicecloud, casefeed

I noticed some strange behaviour in the email publisher action on the case feed. When adding an email address manually it commits the address as soon as I type a '.'; for example when entering example.example@example.com it commits the address as soon as I type the first '.'.

For example following screenshot:

**No point typed yet**
[image]

**The moment I type a point**

[image]

As you can see it just takes example as a contact on the mail making example.example@example.com impossible to add.

Has anyone faced this issue before?

I noticed it works when entering the . via the numpad character. Yet not all keyboards (laptops) don't have these numpads which is a problem.

Could it be related to the type of input/keyboard that is beign used? This seems strange to me though if this would be the case.

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks,

Lieven